# PDF works on Windows but not Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, fonts

On Ubuntu, if I try to view this pdf:
https://gradschool.princeton.edu/sites/gradschool/files/FPO_Examination_Report.pdf

Everything shows up well *except* the second line (the one that contains "having submitted a dissertation as previously reported"). On the beginning of that line, before the textbox, there is just a bunch of garbage characters overlapping each other.

The problem seems to be that the Calibri font is not embedded.

Here is some output that might be of use:

```
$ pdffonts FPO_Examination_Report.pdf 
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
Calibri                              CID TrueType      Identity-H       no  no  no      78  0
BUOFXG+Calibri                       CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     83  0
HCQTDJ+Calibri                       TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     85  0
HCQTDJ+Calibri-Bold                  TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     87  0
HCQTDJ+Calibri-Italic                TrueType          WinAnsi          yes yes yes     89  0



$ pdffonts -subst FPO_Examination_Report.pdf 
name                                 object ID substitute font                      substitute font file
------------------------------------ --------- ------------------------------------ ------------------------------------
Calibri                                  78  0 Carlito                              /usr/share/fonts/truetype/crosextra/Carlito-Regular.ttf
$




$ /usr/bin/gs \
>   -o testing.pdf \
>   -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress \
>   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
>    FPO_Examination_Report.pdf 
GPL Ghostscript 9.15 (2014-09-22)
Copyright (C) 2014 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
Can't find CID font "Calibri".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-Identity for /Calibri, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
The substitute CID font "Adobe-Identity" is not provided either. attempting to use fallback CIDFont.See doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Loading a TT font from /usr/share/ghostscript/9.15/Resource/CIDFSubst/DroidSansFallback.ttf to emulate a CID font Adobe-Identity ... Done.
Can't find CMap Identity-UTF16-H building a CIDDecoding resource. 
Warning: falling back to Identity ordering
Loading a TT font from /usr/share/ghostscript/9.15/Resource/CIDFSubst/DroidSansFallback.ttf to emulate a CID font CIDFallBack ... Done.
Can't find CMap Identity-UTF16-H building a CIDDecoding resource. 
   **** Warning: can't process font stream, loading font by the name.
Can't find CID font "Calibri".
Attempting to substitute CID font /Adobe-Identity for /Calibri, see doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
The substitute CID font "Adobe-Identity" is not provided either. attempting to use fallback CIDFont.See doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution.
Loading a TT font from /usr/share/ghostscript/9.15/Resource/CIDFSubst/DroidSansFallback.ttf to emulate a CID font Adobe-Identity ... Done.
Can't find CMap Identity-UTF16-H building a CIDDecoding resource. 
Warning: falling back to Identity ordering
Loading a TT font from /usr/share/ghostscript/9.15/Resource/CIDFSubst/DroidSansFallback.ttf to emulate a CID font CIDFallBack ... Done.
Can't find CMap Identity-UTF16-H building a CIDDecoding resource. 
   **** Error reading a content stream. The page may be incomplete.
   **** File did not complete the page properly and may be damaged.

   **** This file had errors that were repaired or ignored.
   **** The file was produced by: 
   **** >>>> Adobe PDF Library 9.0 <<<<
   **** Please notify the author of the software that produced this
   **** file that it does not conform to Adobe's published PDF
   **** specification.

$
```